# Does Linux support 2MB pages at compile time?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, operating-system, kernel, page-tables

I know processors these days, some of them, support 2MB and 1GB page sizes. Is it possible to compile the Linux kernel to natively support 2MB as opposed to the standard 4Kb page?

Thanks.

Comment: You mean to always use 2MB pages instead of 4KB pages for all allocations?

Comment: Yes, not just "memory allocation"...I mean everything....the OS using 2MB pages for itself and everything else.

Comment: and the target architecture is x86? Because I'm not aware of any other architecture that supports 2MB pages.

Comment: Yes. That is correct.

Comment: The default page size is specified by the macro `PAGE_SIZE` which is defined in  [linux/arch/x86/include/asm/page_types.h](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/a5532439ebab93e47784effb96aafa7d7ba4b760/arch/x86/include/asm/page_types.h#L11). I'm not really sure whether you can just easily modify that without breaking stuff.

Comment: You can try and change `PAGE_SHIFT` to 21 and see what happens when you compile and run the kernel.

Comment: @HadiBrais: Do you have idea what page mean and how CPU support them? In short: do no mess with fields in CPU registry. CPU support natively 4KB, 4MB (system without PAE)/2MB, 1GB (if system support 4 level pages).

Comment: To explain paging (short, without much details/precision): If CPU has 4 level pages (most Intel bit processors): They have 4 levels of page tables: top level address blocks of 1GB either direct on pointing to a second level page table. Such table as various items pointing to 2MB or 4MB memory (depending if CPU support PAE): either direct access or table with the 4K pages. This last must point to memory (either physical, or just "not present" if it is in disk). -- This is the memory part of paging.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi Not sure why you're explaining the basics of paging to me. I'm confused. Your comments are irrelevant to my comments or OP's question.

Comment: @HadiBrais: I was explaining that paging is a CPU feature not a kernel one. Yous PAGE_SIZE and PAGE_SHIFT refers to CPU structures. CPUs do no read header files, so a #GP is guaranteed. The only answer was in such direction (TBL is the cached version of page lookup tables) which is what OP is asking. We already have 2MB pages, and nzouedi explained how to use large pages in userspace (and my old Linux system already use many 2MB tables).

Answer (score 1):

Well, I can say yes and no.

The page size is fixed. But that depend on your patience to the erros and issues that you will encounter.

The [page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_%28computer_memory%29#Page_size_trade-off) size is known and determined by the [MMU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_management_unit) hardware, so the operating system is taking that into account. However, notice that some Linux systems (and hardware!) have [hugetlbpage](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/vm/hugetlbpage.txt) and Linux [mmap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) might accept `MAP_HUGETLB` (but your code should handle the case of processors or kernels without huge page support, e.g. by calling mmap again without `MAP_HUGETLB` when the first mmap with `MAP_HUGETLB` has failed).

You may find these links interested for you:

- https://www.cloudibee.com/linux-hugepages/
- https://forums.opensuse.org/showthread.php/437078-changing-pagesize-kernel
- https://linuxgazette.net/155/krishnakumar.html
- https://lwn.net/Articles/375096/

Comment: This doesn't answer the question at all. It's even hard to understand what you're trying to say.

Comment: For me, it answer the question. But possibly there is some misunderstanding what are page in CPU (and how they various levels are implemented) and the "block" size (the I/O part of paging).